# why initialized components before SuspendLayout in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

i am designing a windows form in c# .Net fw-3.5,

i have check out the generated code by c# in designer.cs file

```
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();

        this.SuspendLayout();
```

and after SuspendLayout command all components properties are assigning.

my question: is here any special reason to initialize object before SuspendLayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no need to do it beforehand.  Object initialization is irrelevant to the `SuspendLayout` call, so why do it before?  Even autogenerated code can be laid out logically.  If I were writing that code by hand I would do the same thing for the same reason I declare variables as close as possible to where they are first used (of course, that example would make the generation process a bit more complicated, so they just initialize them at the start).

Comment: yes, i am writing designer code manually, if all code relating one object is at one place then it is easy to understand by others, and easy to do change, so that's why i ask this question here. thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's really not going to make any difference either way - it's not like the components have been *added* to the form yet, so it won't be placing them, then suspending layout, then changing everything.

I suspect it just makes it easier for the code to be generated if all the variables are assigned and *then* used, rather than having to work out whether there were any dependencies between the various objects.

Comment: i am writing designer code myself, if i initialize objects after SuspendLayout, then is it ok ? or it may effects execution ?

Comment: @Haider: It won't affect anything so long as you can make sure you've initialized variables before you refer to them elsewhere.

Comment: yes, that is understood, i will initialize variables before refer it